# Remapping ctrl+win

Tags: autohotkey

The first script works, but the second that should remap ctrl+win does not. Why is that?

1. `ctrl::Send {ALT down}{SHIFT down}{SHIFT up}{ALT up}`
2. `^lwin::Send {ALT down}{SHIFT down}{SHIFT up}{ALT up}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are both modifier keys.

Try this instead:

```
Ctrl & LWin::
```

---

**Edit**:
Then, try using [SetKeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) and possibly [SendEvent](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendEvent), too.

Wait, I found this working just now:

```
Ctrl & LWin::Send {ALT down}{SHIFT down}
Ctrl & LWin Up::Send {SHIFT up}{ALT up}
```

Of course, being modifier keys, they need special treatment.

**Edit 2**:

> My shift+alt combination is for changing the keyboard language

Why didn't you say so earlier? : ) I thought you were just replacing modifier combinations.

It's much simpler, then.

This should work:

```
/*
cf. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm
cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632630(v=vs.85).aspx

0x50: WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST
0x02: INPUTLANGCHANGE_FORWARD
*/
Ctrl & LWin::PostMessage, 0x50, 2,,, A
```

Alternatively:

```
Ctrl & LWin::
    KeyWait Ctrl
    KeyWait LWin
    PostMessage, 0x50, 2,,, A
Return
```

The above two pieces of code have pros and cons. Experiment and choose what suits your needs.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What OS are you using? I am with Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Same here. Why don't you try looking into the key history, then?

Comment: What do you mean with key history?

Comment: Double-click the tray icon of the script and press ctrl+k. And ctrl+H will help, too.

Comment: `d LControl` and `d LWin` are followed by generated `LAlt` and `LShift`, and up (`u`) events are processed and generated **normally**, too. It indicates **no problems** at all.

Comment: Then the problem is probably something on my system.

Comment: that, or somewhere else in your script

Comment: I just read another comment of yours on the other answer. Try the new code.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me:

```
Ctrl & LWin:: msgbox hi
```

I think the keys `Alt` and `Shift` are triggering while you still have not released the keys `Ctrl` and `Win`, therefore it’s working all the keys at the same time: `Alt`, `Shift`, `Ctrl`, `Win`.
Because you just should check if the keys are not pressed at that time.
To do this, we’ll use the function `GetKeyState()`.

```
Ctrl & LWin Up::
    while(!GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P"))
        continue
    send {ALT down}{SHIFT down}
    sleep 40
    send {SHIFT up}{ALT up}
    ; or use “Send {ALT down}{SHIFT down}{SHIFT up}{ALT up}”
    ; if it works for you
return
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. My shift+alt combination is for changing the keyboard language, but the keyboard language is not changing when pressing ctrl+win.

Comment: keyboard layout can be changed by `postmessage`